# Google Cloud Messaging - different accounts for GCM setup and app publishing

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an application for a customer. The process of app publishing is completely on the customer (I don't own the account that is used for publishing).

Now I am adding Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to the app. So to make GCM prerequisites, using the [Google APIs Console web site](https://code.google.com/apis/console) I have to (1) create a Google API project and enable the GCM Service and (2) obtain the Server API Key.

Obviously the only account I can use for making GCM prerequisites is my own account.

I am concerned about the generated GCM prerequisites may not work in production, because of different Google accounts used for publishing the app and for making GCM prerequisites. Also what if I then remove/modify Google API project from my account by mistake? Are my concerns valid? There seems to be no info on this topic.

Comment: I think it's okay even if you have different accounts for GCM setup and app publishing. As far as I know, the GCM key is the only required for sending push notifications. You may check it [here](http://docs.twixlmedia.com/m/twixl-publisher-app/l/243432-deploying-an-android-app-in-google-play). I have tried uploading .apk to the Store using different account and it seems there is no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreeing with @abielita in the comments section, the GCM service should still work regardless if the config details are from a different account than that of the one that published it.

The thing that will be complicated is when there is something modified in your project (the one associated with the GCM service) that caused the GCM service to stop, the client will have to try and debug/troubleshoot the issue, which they might contact Google for. And the thing is, I don't think Google (or any company in this matter) would disclose any details of any project that isn't officially their own without any consent from the owner (you). This might delay the process to resolving some things.

With all that said, I would suggest that as much as possible, use the same project, or at the very least, have your client create their own project that you can use for the GCM/FCM service.